# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'tasks'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, frontend, state

I get data from backend and set to my state in componentdidmount but value not set after log state

```
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const getTasks = async () => {
    const getTodoInformation = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
    };
    if (getTodoInformation.email) {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:9000/api/todo/get",
        getTodoInformation
      );
      setTasks(response.data.data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
    console.log(tasks);
  }, []);
```

My tasks is empty when i log it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the title and the question itself are actually two questions.

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'tasks'. Either includes it or remove the dependency array

That's because you include a state (i.e. `tasks`) in the `useEffect` hook. And React is basically asking you, "Do you mean run `console.log(tasks)` every time `tasks` is updated?". Because what you are doing is run the `useEffect` hook once and only once.

And for your "actual" question

> value not set after log state

In short, states are set in async manner in React. That means `tasks` is not necessary immediately updated right after you call `setTasks`. See @JBallin comment for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);     
   useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(async () => {
  const getTodoInformation = {
      email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
    };
    if (getTodoInformation.email) {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:9000/api/todo/get",
    getTodoInformation
  );
  setTasks(response.data.data);
}
  }, 1000);
console.log(tasks);
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that useEffect -> is a sync method, getTasks() is asynchronous, and useEffect only works once when your component mounts. Shortly speaking, you got your data from the backend after useEffect worked.

For example, if you will add one more useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(tasks);
}, [tasks]);
```

You will see log, after your data will have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-calling `async` function inside `useEffect` as shown here:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

const getTasks = async () => {
  const getTodoInformation = {
    email: localStorage.getItem("tokenEmail"),
  };

  if (getTodoInformation.email) {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:9000/api/todo/get",
      getTodoInformation
    );

    return response.data.data;
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const tasks = await getTasks();

    setTasks(tasks);
  })();

  console.log(tasks);
}, [tasks]);
```